# Unifrom Convergence of series of product of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Suppose {$f_n$}, {$g_n$} defined on $E$ and,

(a) $\Sigma f_n$ has uniformly bounded partial sums;
(b) $g_n \to 0$ uniformly on $E$
(c) $g_1(x)\geq g_2(x)\geq g_3(x)\geq ...$ for every $x \in E$.

Prove that $\Sigma f_n g_n$ converges uniformly on $E$.

My solution:

By uniform convergence of $g,  \exists N\in \Bbb N$ s.t.$|g_n|\leq \epsilon/q$ for $n\geq N$ and $q$ being the upper bound on  $\Sigma f_n$.

By Cauchy Criterion for convergence and choosing $M,N \geq N$, we have

$|\Sigma_{M+1}^{N} f_k g_k|\leq \Sigma_{M+1}^{N}  |f_k g_k|\leq \Sigma_{M+1}^{N}  |f_k| |g_k|\leq |g_k|\Sigma_{M+1}^{N} |f_k| \leq \epsilon q/q= \epsilon$,

Is the solution correct? Please point out the flaws.
Thanks

Comment: The boundedness assumption is for $\left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^N f_n(x)\right\rvert$, not for $\sum_{n=0}^N \lvert f_n(x)\rvert$. Do you know the Dirichlet criterion for convergence?

Comment: No, I don't know. Please elaborate

Comment: @Crostul: Agree

Comment: The premises here are that the hypotheses of Dirichlet's criterion hold uniformly on $E$. Hence the conclusion holds uniformly on $E$, i.e. $\sum f_n g_n$ is uniformly convergent. Use summation by parts to prove it, if you can't directly appeal to Dirichlet.